# Create a simple "subway" map in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, statistics, gis

I'm making an small logistics-oriented map...
I got an datatable containing users and their current locations (like station names), i got an image with all the "stations" and routes between 'em.

Current task is to warn when two users might meet (i.e. one user is one-two stations far from other one) and make statistics report (what stations users visit most), but i don't know where to start. 
What's the most economic way to implement this?

I looked on GIS software, but i don't know how to make roads - and work with them too; there's  too much unneeded stuff and no functions i need, or i did not found them so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you do it with php+JS(jQuery) and SQL? Because I think it's the bettter way to do this. Like an in-line app.

But if you really need to do this with VB.net I will try to answer your question:

The most economic way to implement this (I think) Is to make your own functions writen in .net something like:

```
Function get_number_of_users_in(stationID)
Function draw_user_in_image(userID)
and all the functions you may need...
```

After this, you can start to making your main program with a graphic interface, you could simply add a timmer to refresh your countent (Images, with a position...)

You can implement a grid and put your image over it, so you can display users like a point in X,Y coordenate. Like:

```
******************************
*       Your image           *
* -------------------------- *
* -                        - *
* -     Your grid          - *
* -------------------------- *
******************************
```

Next, you set the fixed coordenates like Station-1 = [(4,5)]

And controle the position with something like this in your main prg:

```
If get_user_next_to_station(userID) Then
    msgBox('An user is close to station'&get_station_name(stationID)'!!')
EndIf
```

Sory for my probably erros in VB that's been a while I didn't touch this language xD But it's only for show you how you can do this.

Well I think this is the way I would do it, that depends on you and your time and skills in programming. Hope this helped you, if you need more help, you can ask me, there is no problem. Good luck !

Comment: Well, i was thinking about that too, but there's... 200+ stations each has 3-7 neighbours, ~150 users - it might be a bit slow... Well if there will be no other options i'll stick with it. I don't know PHP+JS good so no to it...thanks :)

Comment: Did you finally find something better to do this? Sorry I'm curious about this projet because I find it very interesting.